# How to display a mysql table with php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I am relatively new to mysql and I have followed a tutorial to get my database to display. I used PHP and I can't find any errors but it doesn't show. Can anyone help?

Thanks

The name of the server is "sql306.iceiy.com"

The name of the rows are "Exercise_Name", "Muscle_Name" and "PPS"

```
        $servername = "sql306.iceiy.com";
        $username = "icei_32733650";
        $password = "ZoD473049gais";

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
          echo("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        echo "Connected!";

        $sql = "SELECT Exercise_Name, Muscle_Name, PPS, FROM gym_exercises";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "Table";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Exercise_Name</th>";
                echo "<th>Muscle_Name</th>";
                echo "<th>PPS</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Exercise_Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Muscle_Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['PPS'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR:";
}
 
// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
      ?>
```

Comment: What doesn't show?

Comment: It looks like you are using some really bad tutorial. I highly encourage you to find something better. If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection. Here are some good video tutorials https://youtu.be/2eebptXfEvw & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVbEyFZKgqk&list=PLr3d3QYzkw2xabQRUpcZ_IBk9W50M9pe-

Comment: @Dharman The sql table is supposed to show

Comment: What do you see? Did you check the "view source" to see what the generated HTML looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues with your code:

1. You need to specify the database in which the relation(s) you are processing exist: `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databaseName);`.
2. You have an extra comma in your select statement.
3. Since you are using the object-oriented style in connecting, you should continue with that style for consistency. Moreover, I don't see where variable `$link` has been defined.
4. You don't have a proper **<table>** tag.

In the code below I have eliminated doing calls to `echo`. There is nothing wrong with that *per se*. It's just a question of what is neater and clearer.

Also, there could be values in the table that could be mistaken for HTML tags if any of the data contains '<' and/or '>'. If so, then you will want to replace these characters with *HTML entities*, for example `htmlentities(row['PPS'])`.

```PHP
<?php

$servername = "sql306.iceiy.com";
$username = "icei_32733650";
$password = "ZoD473049gais";
$databasename = "some_database_name";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databasename);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    return; /* Do not execute remaining code */
}

//echo "Connected!"; /* do not put this out */

$sql = "SELECT Exercise_Name, Muscle_Name, PPS FROM gym_exercises";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Exercise_Name</th>
        <th>Muscle_Name</th>
        <th>PPS</th>
    </tr>
<?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['Exercise_Name']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['Muscle_Name']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['PPS']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
        }
?>
</table>
<?php
    }
    else {
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
    // Free result set
    $result->free();
}
else {
    echo "ERROR";
}

// Close connection
$conn->close();
```